# Constant data history sampled by accelerometer

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

I am wondering if there is any possibility to remain constant number of samples in file from my accelerometers. Here is my piece of code:

```
void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc) {                                                                        
    struct akcel_wynik *result = malloc(sizeof(struct akcel_wynik));
    getData(result);
    char buff[255];
    sprintf(buff,"%.3f %.3f %.3f \n",result->akcel1_x * ACCEL_CONVERSION_FACTOR,akcel1_y * ACCEL_CONVERSION_FACTOR,akcel1_z * ACCEL_CONVERSION_FACTOR);
    fprintf(ptr,buff);
    free(result);
}
```

Basicly: I am saving a sample from accelerometer to my txt file ever 2 miliseconds. After measurement I am ploting data from txtfile using python matplotlib. I want to try ploting data in real time. Thats why i want to have constant number of samples in my file. If my file reaches maximum number, I want to overwrite old samples. Is there any possibility to do that? I would also like to ask if there is a other way to transfer data from process (written in C) to my python GUI program in real time?

Comment: Why is `result` dynamically allocated in this case? Will `struct akcel_wynik` be huge (for example, more than 4MiB)?

Comment: An other way -> communication via socket, for example.

Comment: @MikeCAT Ure right. Thats not necessary there.

Comment: @MikeCAT akcel_wynik contains 6 uint16_t types.

Comment: I didn't get why do you need file at all?